# How do i make PHP echo only inside div?

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a page that displays RSS feed posts inside cards, everything is fine except only 1 card is being placed inside the `div` that has the `flex flex-wrap` class, causing the cards being placed vertically.

[Screenshot of how the cards are placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTf3a.png)

[Screenshot of how the code is being created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoHbu.png)

My HTML and PHP code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
  <style>
  body{
      padding: 25px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex flex-wrap">

<?php include 'rss.php';?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My "rss.php" PHP code

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "https://phpexample1.000webhostapp.com/feed.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    $image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children('media', True)->content->attributes();
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

    $html .= "<div class='w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/6 mb-4'><div class='max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg'>  <a href='$link'><img class='w-full' src='$image' alt='$title'></a>";
    $html .= "<a href='$link'><div class='px-6 py-4'> <div class='font-bold text-xl mb-2'>$title</div></a>";
    $html .= "<p class='text-gray-700 text-base'>$description</p>";
    $html .= "<p class='text-gray-600'>$pubDate</p></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you echo out each card in its own div so they all align?

Comment: I'm new to PHP so i don't know much.

Comment: Could you do it in a way so each card is echoed in the same way but within its own DIV so they can flex more accurately. I think you can solve it with some minor CSS adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got too many closing /div in your code, i just indented my way but you can reorder as you like. Maybe it resolve the problem.

```
$url = "https://phpexample1.000webhostapp.com/feed.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    $image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children('media', True)->content->attributes();
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

    echo "<div class='w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/6 mb-4'>
            <div class='max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg'>
                <a href='$link'>
                    <img class='w-full' src='$image' alt='$title'>
                </a>
                <a href='$link'>
                    <div class='px-6 py-4'>
                        <div class='font-bold text-xl mb-2'>$title</div>
                        <p class='text-gray-700 text-base'>$description</p>
                        <p class='text-gray-600'>$pubDate</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
```